# mysql odbc executeBatch takes long time

Tags: java, mysql, odbc, batch-updates

I'm writing back data of a table in Java to my MYSQl dB. But to execute one executeBatch it takes 1.241 s! Here my code:

```
updateLieferant = conn.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE "+dbnames.artikel.name+" SET Abteilung = ? , statusAusmessen = ? , Status = ? " 
    +" WHERE " +dbnames.auftragsnummer +" = ? " +" AND " +dbnames.artikelnummer +" = ?");

updateLieferant.setString( 1, "blabla" );
updateLieferant.setString( 2, "blabla" );
updateLieferant.setString( 3, "blabla" );
updateLieferant.setString( 4, "blabla");
updateLieferant.setString( 5, "blabla" );

long time = System.nanoTime(); 
updateLieferant.executeBatch();
time = System.nanoTime()- time;

System.out.println(time/1000000);
```

outputs 1241 ms... is there anything I'm doing wrong? From this page I see that it should take around 100ms.
http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.ch/2011/08/fast-inserts-to-postgresql-with-jdbc.html

Answer (score 0):

executeBatch of for executing a statement a large number of times, as in the BPI section in the link you posted (it's in a loop), but here you are executing it only once.

Instead, try

```
updateLieferant.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: True, but I am acutally doing this in a loop. With executeUpdate() i get a time of 657 ms which is still 3 times more than what I see in the posted link.

Comment: In that case, you problem is probably not with JDBC but with the database itself. How big is the table you are updating, and do you have indexes on the columns in the WHERE clause?

Comment: No I am not using indexes. The table has 316813 rows and 15 columns

Comment: I suggest adding indexes to the columns used in the WHERE clause. That should speed things up - without them it has to do a sequential scan of all 316813 rows for both columns to check which rows to update. An index scan will be much faster.

Comment: Brilliant! That made the job! Now I'm where I wanted to be. 
Thanks a lot!